# MYSQL working slowly as query with subquery than 2 queries (+php)

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have table (about 80'000 rows), looks like

```
id, parentId, col1, col2, col3...
 1,     null, 'A', 'B', 'C'
 2,        1, ...
 3,        1, ...
 4,     null, ...
 5,        4, ...
```

(one level parent - child only)

and I need get all dependent rows -

```
SELECT ... 
FROM table 
WHERE id = :id OR parentId = :id OR id IN (
    SELECT parentId 
    FROM table 
    WHERE id = :id
    )
```

but why this request working slowly instead 2 request - if I get parentId on php first?

```
$t = executeQuery('SELECT parentId FROM table WHERE id = :Id;', $id);
if ($t) {
    $id = $t;
}

$t = executeQuery('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :id OR parentId = :id ORDER BY id;', $id);
```

PS: max depends rows < 70

PPS:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY product ALL PRIMARY,parentId    NULL    NULL    NULL    73415   Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  product const   PRIMARY,parentId    PRIMARY 4   const   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `IN` for an equal `=`

```
SELECT ... 
FROM table 
WHERE id = :id OR parentId = :id OR id = (
    SELECT parentId 
    FROM table 
    WHERE id = :id
    )
```

or change it to a join:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM table 
    inner join ( 
        SELECT parentId 
        FROM table 
        WHERE id = :id
    ) s on s.parentID = table.id or s.parentID = table.parentID
```

Comment: YES! The first one working faster when **All** my examples! Thank you!

Comment: i dont see how changing `IN` to `=` makes it significantly faster. Both cases dont use indexes. Also the inner join variant does not give a right result.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the first case, MySQL need to create an intermediate result, store it in memory and then iterate over it to find all the relevant id in the table. In the second way, assuming you correctly created an index on id and parent id, it simply go straigth to the index, find the relevant rows, and send you back the result immediately.

Answer (score 1):

UNION works faster for this case

this allows first query to user UNION INDEX and second just uses inner join, then merges results.

```
SELECT *
FROM `table` 
WHERE id = :id OR parentId = :id
UNION
SELECT t1.*
FROM `table` t1 JOIN `table` t2 ON t2.parentId = t1.id AND t2.id = :id
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a long shot but in first case you have "IN" statement of the WHERE part of the query. Maybe MySQL tries to optimize the query as if there would be multiple options and in the second case there is no IN part, so the compiled query is more straight forward for the database - thus utilizing the indexes in better manner.

Basically for 2 queries on the same connection the overhead of performing the queries should be minimal and irelevant in this case. Also subqueries in general are not very optimizable by the query parser. Try using JOIN instead (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

An `EXPLAIN` might shed some more light on the problem for you.

Look into `EXISTS`, or rewriting your query as a `JOIN`.

Comment: From your explain, it's not using an index for the outer query.